# Why is the particles not showing when player dies, it works fine on it's own but not when it hits a hurt object? (I am working on a 2D game)

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I am trying to add a particle effect to my player when it dies and hits a hurt object. I have tested the particle effect on its own and its working fine. It's when the player hits the hurt object the particle effect isn't showing but I can see that it's hitting it from looking at the sidebar it says deathSplosion(Clone)(see image attached)[deathSposion level manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzB9U.png)
. I have created the particle effect as a prefab and added it to the levelManager (see image attached).[Side bar death sposions appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzB9U.png)

Does anyone know why the particle effect isn't appearing when the player hits a hurt object? Thanks!

```
 public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
 public float waitToRespawn;
 public PlayerController thePlayer;
 public GameObject deathSplosion;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
 public void Respawn()
 {
     StartCoroutine("RespawnCo");
 }
 public IEnumerator RespawnCo()
 {
     thePlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     Instantiate(deathSplosion, thePlayer.transform.position, 
    thePlayer.transform.rotation);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitToRespawn);
     thePlayer.transform.position = thePlayer.respawnPosition;
     thePlayer.gameObject.SetActive(true);
 }
```

This is my code also for when the player respawns.

```
public class hurtPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    private LevelManager theLevelManager;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        theLevelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        {
            theLevelManager.Respawn();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the object to inactive *before* the particle system spawns, so it is not happening. Instead of setting inactive first, just turn off the renderer for the object first.

In the case of a 2D Game:

```
public IEnumerator RespawnCo()
{
    thePlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>.enabled = false;
    Instantiate(deathSplosion, thePlayer.transform.position, 
    thePlayer.transform.rotation);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitToRespawn);
    thePlayer.transform.position = thePlayer.respawnPosition;
    thePlayer.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>.enabled = true;
}
```

You can modify this code to suit your needs! Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I will try this out.

Comment: Well, he isn't. He is instantiating a new one. He is only setting the position. That overload doesn't set a parent object.